# Swift View "Bouncing" On Keyboard Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, hide, show

I am writing an app where the user must type a word in a text box and then press a button to see if they entered the correct word.  When the user taps on the textbox, I want the view to be shifted up so that nothing is obstructed by the keyboard.  I use the following code to accomplish this shift and the resulting shift back down after the keyboard has been dismissed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    var info:NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    self.view.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize.height)
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

    var info:NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    self.view.frame.origin.y += (keyboardSize.height)
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when the user has the keyboard showing and presses the button, the keyboard is dismissed and then the view is shifted

Comment: So to confirm what is going on, your keyboard is being dismissed when you hit a button, but you'd like the keyboard to stay there? Or just the view to stay there?

Comment: so what happens is keyboard dismisses...delay...then view shifts to original place?

Comment: @Dustin that's right, the keyboard dismisses, then there's a delay, then the view quickly shifts down partially below the bottom of the screen, then back to the normal position.

Comment: id use constraints instead of setting frames to make the view move. also you could play around keyboardWillHide and keyboardDidHide or a delay to sync these actions. I think the bounce is due to frame vs constraint.

Comment: I use your code and it is working perfectly for me. so thank you... sorry for your issues

Comment: I'm now facing the Issue, that the screen pops up twice, if I fastly click threw the screen :S